# 12 или 24 часовой формат

Tags: python

Если время находится в диапазоне от 1 до 12 то 12 часовое
если от 0 до 24 то 24 часовое
если неоднозначно то вывести 'both' не проходит проверку если одно число меньше 12 или равно 12

```
a = input()
b = input()
a = a[0:2]
b = b[0:2]

if a[0] == '0':
  a = a[1]
if b[0] == '0':
  b = b[1]
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
if (a and b) < 12:
  print('12-hour clock')
if (a or b) == 12 and (a or b)>12:
  print('both')
if (a or b) > 12:
  print('24-hour clock')
```

Comment: Все верно. Вы же сравниваете булево значение с целочисленным.

Comment: Часть ``if a[0] == '0':
      a = a[1]
    if b[0] == '0':
      b = b[1]`` (пардон за код в камментах) вообще не нужна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
if (a and b) < 12:
  print('12-hour clock')
if (a or b) == 12 and (a or b)>12:
  print('both')
if (a or b) > 12:
  print('24-hour clock')
```

нужно писать

```
if a < 12 and b < 12:
  print('12-hour clock')
if (a == 12 or b == 12) and (a > 12 or b > 12):
  print('both')
if a > 12 or b > 12:
  print('24-hour clock')
```

Comment: Что будет при a = 12 и b = 12? В общем, писать, может, нужно и так, но сам алгоритм ошибочный.